# Jar file of java

Tags: java, debian, debian-based

I have created a java application and packed it into a jar file on a Windows platform. Now I wants to deploy that jar file on Debian Linux.

1. Will the same jar file work for Debian Linux?
2. Is the command, used in windows for executing a jar file from the command prompt, same for Debain Linux?

i.e.

```
java -jvm "MyJar.jar"
```

Will the above command work for Debian Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Jar files are portable across platforms, and the syntax of the jar command is the same on both Linux and Windows.

---

EDIT:  You should use the latest version of Sun Java unless there is a *very* good reason not to.  Installation instructions: http://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun

Answer (score 7):

Generally, it should. However this depends on a few conditions:

- If you use native code (JNI) you must make sure that the native library is available for the target platform
- You must make sure you have no paths hardcoded which are Windows specific (in fact you should even watch out for special characters like the Path seperator : vs. ;)
- You cannot use Runtime specific code

Comment: +1 I've seen a LOT of Java apps written and tested only on Windows fall down hard on a Mac or Linux machine. WORA is a goal to work toward, not a proof against carelessly written software.

Comment: The behavior of the Java program inside the jar file is outside what the poster asked (but will most likely be relevant very shortly after actually running the java command on the system)

Answer (score 4):

**1. Will the same jar file work for Debian Linux?**

> > Yes. Hence the nature of Java (portable code)

**2.  Is the command, used in windows for executing a jar file from the command prompt, same for Debain Linux?**

> > java -jar "MyJar.jar"

Answer (score 2):

yes, the main idea of java is that it (should) run on different operating systems, as long as a java runtime is installed.

though i have never heard of the -jvm flag.

if you want to start a jar file you should use the -jar flag.

```
java -jar "MyJar.jar"
```

you can also read up on the [Write once run anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) principle.

Answer (score 2):

I do my development on a mac but run in linux and windows environments without any problem. Key is not to use JNI, As everyone else have mentioned I would use `java -jar "MyJar.jar"`

Answer (score 1):

Almost. Use:

java -jar "MyJar.jar"

And of course you shouldn't have used anything such JNI or runtime stuff

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you might want to do, in Linux:

```
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

Instead of:

```
java -jvm YourJar.jar
```